# Is it posible to use PDOException in other scope?

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I am creating new PDO connection inside class constructor and then use it only in that class. If some error occurs i get fatal error instead of `PDOException`.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not fou.....

My code is:

```
class Helper
{
    private $_db;

    function __construct($config = FALSE)
    {

        $this->_db = new PDO($config['database']['dsn'], $config['database']['username'], $config['database']['password'], $config['database']['options']);
        $this->_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
}

$config = array(
    'database' => array(
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname,
        'username' => $dblogin,
        'password' => $dbpass,
        'options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
        )
    )
);

try {
    $helper = new Helper($config);
} catch (PDOException $error) {
    die('Database Error: ' . $error->getMessage());
}
```

So is it possible ?

Comment: It should be possible. PDO is promoting itself with that feature (among others).

Comment: @11684 But as i said - i get only fatal error

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the fact you don't call the `__construct()` method yourself. What happens if you move the code from the constructor to an instance method (`foo`, for example) and then do this in your try-block: `$helper = new Helper(); $helper->foo($config)`.

Comment: What is the purpose of this Helper class? is it database helper or something else?

Comment: @11684 i have in constructor also other exceptions,for example `InvalidArgumentException` and it works fine if config is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is it possible ?

Of course. That's the very purpose of Exceptions actually.

> i get fatal error instead of PDOException.

This is not quite true. You actually get an exception, though uncaught one (which, in turn, leads to fatal error).

Regarding your current error - most likely it is caused by some other block of code. There is always a stack trace provided with an exception - so, you can easily find it out. You may catch it there then.

However, I would advise against catching it manually. It would be better to create an exception handler and catch all the exceptions in one place (unless you want to handle error somehow, which is seldom occirred)

Comment: problem is that i defined exception, but it fires as undefined `Uncaught exception 'PDOException'`

Comment: so i need to fix it and catch that exception

Comment: Well - just catch it. By the way, why do you want it? PDO errors seldom have to be caught.